# Sort Month Name in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, t-sql

My Current Query is :

```
SELECT FORMAT(Date, 'MMM') as 'Date', FORMAT(Date, 'yyy') as 'Year' 
,COUNT(*) 
as 'Tickets Generated'
FROM [SambaData2].[dbo].[Tickets]
GROUP BY FORMAT(Date, 'MMM'), FORMAT(Date, 'yyy')
ORDER BY Date
```

It returns the values:

[image]

I would like the same query to return sorted month name with Year!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use year(date), month(date) in order by
month() function will give you month number so you can order it easily

```
SELECT FORMAT(Date, 'MMM') as 'Date', FORMAT(Date, 'yyy') as 'Year',
COUNT(*) 
as 'Tickets Generated'
FROM [SambaData2].[dbo].[Tickets]
GROUP BY FORMAT(Date, 'MMM'), FORMAT(Date, 'yyy'),year(Date),month(Date)
ORDER BY year(Date),month(Date)
```

Comment: Done! Added the same Order by clause in Group by and It works! Thanks! @fa06

Answer (score 2):

For greater query efficiency I would avoid the format() approach.

```
select
       left(datename(month,[Date]),3) [Month]
     , year([Date]) [Year]
     , [Tickets Generated]
from (
        SELECT
               dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,t.[Date]),0) as [Date]
             , COUNT(*) as [Tickets Generated]
        FROM [SambaData2].[dbo].[Tickets] AS t
        GROUP BY dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,t.[Date]),0)
    ) as d
ORDER BY [Date]
```

The core to this approach is the following:

```
dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,t.[Date]),0)
```

this has the effect of locating the first day of the relevant year & month, thus leaving a whole date available for the order by clause, but still grouping to the required level. Runing the foillowing may help explain

```
select 
  datediff(month,0,getdate()) a
, dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate()),0) b
, left(datename(month,getdate()),3) c
, getdate() d


   a          b        c              d           
 ------- ------------ ----- --------------------- 
  1425    2018-10-01   Oct   2018-10-04 08:08:19
```

Comment: Yes. Grouping by _formatted_ data is nonsense. Format the data after grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(Date, 'yyy') AS Year,
    FORMAT(Date, 'MMM') AS Date,
    COUNT(*) AS [Tickets Generated]
FROM [SambaData2].[dbo].[Tickets]
GROUP BY
    FORMAT(Date, 'yyy'),
    FORMAT(Date, 'MMM')
ORDER BY
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, FORMAT(Date, 'yyy') + '-' + FORMAT(Date, 'MMM'));
```

I prefer this method over the accepted answer because it is only uses components in the `ORDER BY` clause which were actually present in the `SELECT` clause.  Certain RDBMS would complain about an `ORDER BY` using components not present in `SELECT`.  This answer also assumes that your version of SQL Server supports `TRY_CONVERT`.